# boost fusion question

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I'm having trouble compiling the following (I'm new at fusion). In particular, I'm not sure where "_" (in is_same) comes from? From boost::lambda? Boost::mpl? What include do I need for this to compile?

```
template <typename T>
struct check
{ 
  const T& value;

  check(const T& v) : value(v) {}

  template <typename X>
  bool operator()(const fusion::pair<X,T>& data) const
  {
    return data.second == value;
  }
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename P>
bool new_match(const P& p, const T2& values)
{
  fusion::for_each(fusion::filter_if<boost::is_same<_, T2> >(p), check(values));
  return true; // not finished, just trying to compile
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that indeed is meant to be `boost::mpl::_`, as demonstrated in [the `fusion::filter_if` documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/transformation/functions/filter_if.html), so you should only need `#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>` and a qualification or using declaration to bring `_` into scope.

Comment: I read the doc only up to point, and saw only the example in the introduction... I didn't check the ref for filter_if :-( Thanks for the pointer! :-)

Comment: @Frank : No worries. :-] To be fair, the Fusion documentation definitely assumes deep prior knowledge of MPL and often conflates symbols from both libraries without much explanation.